# Could two companies share one Stack Overflow Teams instance and split the invoice?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible for two companies to purchase the seats for one SO private site? Basically, those two companies will split the invoice and will need SO to issue two separate invoices to these two companies. Or does SO have any suggestions as to how to handle this case?

Comment: We have several options for our Teams product - https://stackoverflow.com/teams/ two offer billing as an option, Business and Enterprise but I'm not sure if splitting it is possible. If you're talking about a full Enterprise instance, you're going to want to reach out to our Enterprise sales team to discuss these details. If you're interested in a Business Team, I can move your question to Meta Stack Overflow and get someone from Support to answer this.

Comment: @Catija, thanks. We are in Business license.

Comment: @Catija Hi Catija, once you move my question to somewhere else, would you pls let me know the location of the question so I can see the answer? thanks

Comment: @Zinna You seem to be already looking at the new location of your question which is at Stack Overflow Meta.

Comment: @PolyGeo that's why I am a bit confused. I originally opened my question in Stack Overflow Meta and I saw it will be moved to Stack Overflow Meta? I thought there is another location or something. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @zinna originally your question was at [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), which is for global stack exchange. If you are taking about Stack Overflow, then this is meta.stackoverflow. You are at the right place, and your question has no answers yet.

Comment: FYI, there's an [active discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362494/348196) on whether Teams questions are on-topic on Meta.SE or if they should be asked exclusively on Meta.SO. @10Rep CC:Zinna.

Comment: @10Rep Thanks a lot for the clarification and info. Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not currently possible, nor is that currently on our roadmap.

We will only issue one invoice and accept only one source of payment. One of you would need to pay the invoices, and the other would need to reimburse you for their share.